# How to show a comma separated number with StringFormat in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, string-formatting

My code currently shows like this: `43521 reviews`, I want it be like this: `43,521 reviews`. How can I do that? and is there a full reference for all possible formats in `StringFormat`? couldn't find anything. thanks.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews,StringFormat='{}{0} reviews'}"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just change your string format like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews,StringFormat='{}{0:0,0} reviews'}"/>
```

Comment: That's one way around it, but what if the string is in a sentence `{Binding Company, StringFormat="If error persists, please contact {0}"

Answer (score 14):

This one also worked :)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews,StringFormat='{}{0:N0} reviews'}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews,StringFormat='{}{0:#,0} reviews'}"/>
```

Comment: Other solution returns 01 when number is 1, but this solution return 1 when number is 1. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This is what i use for showing comma with 2 decimal precision

```
<Label Content="{Binding Reviews}" ContentStringFormat="{0:N2} reviews" />
```