# C# WPF - Format number with commas while typing in text box

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose there is this text box and when a user types **4000**, as soon as the last zero is typed, the text box should show **4,000** If a user types, **2030040**, it should show **2,030,040** adding the commas in real time. I want to do this in a WPF C# project. I have added the following code so that the user can only type numbers and decimal points in the text box. **txtAmount** is the name of the text box.

```
private void txtAmount_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.Text.Last()) && !(e.Text.Last() == '.');
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296001/how-to-show-a-comma-separated-number-with-stringformat-in-xaml

Comment: @Coops Looks like that's for text block, but I wanna do this in text box only.

Comment: Apologies I thought that StringFormat worked for TextBox's too

Comment: @Coops It's okay. I thought it would work as well but it didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Besides your preview textinput handler, you will need to bind textbox to int/long variable along with stringformat

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}" 
         PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            var currentText = textBox.Text;

            if (currentText.Length + 1 < 3) return;

            if ((textBox.GetDigitsCount()) % 3 == 0 && currentText.Length != 2)
            {
                textBox.Text = !textBox.HasAnyCommas() 
                    ? currentText.Insert(1, ",") 
                    : textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.Text.Length - 2, ",");
            }

            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
        }


public static class Ex
    {
        public static int GetDigitsCount(this TextBox @this) => @this.Text.Count(char.IsDigit);
        public static bool HasAnyCommas(this TextBox @this) => @this.Text.Any(x => x == ',');
    }
```